# How to calculate the variance of an image excluding a list of circles

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision

I have a grayscale image and a list of circles and I am trying to calculate the variance of the image while excluding any pixel located inside one of the circles.

My current implementation is very slow (looping through the image and checking each pixel if it's inside one of the circles).

I tried setting the circles to the mean of the image (to eliminate their effect on the variance) but this has a different result since the mean is calculated on the original image.

What can I do to get this to run more efficiently?

```py
def variance_without_circles(image, circles):
    mean = 0
    sum_squared = 0
    count = 0
    for i in range(image.shape[0]):
        for j in range(image.shape[1]):
            if is_in_circles(circles, i, j):
                continue
            else:
                count += 1
                val = image[i, j]
                mean += val
                sum_squared += val ** 2
    mean = mean / count
    variance = sum_squared / count - mean ** 2
    return variance
```

```
def is_in_circles(circles, i, j):
    for c in circles[0]:
        if (c[0] - j)**2 + (c[1] - i)**2 < (c[2] ** 2):
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: I'm thinking it would help if you gave a realistic image and a realistic list of circles so we know what we are dealing with! Failing that, copy the image and fill it with black, i.e. `mask = np.zeros_like(image)` then draw the circles on in white and make a masked array calculation of variance.

Comment: Cool - you can add it as an answer and accept it yourself (perfectly permitted on SO) so that others can find and see the correct answer and you can bag the points. Well done, and thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Mark Setchel's comment, I used numpy's `masked_array`.

Create a black mask and color the circles white. Then calculate the variance on the masked array:

```
def variance_without_circles(image, circles):
    mask = np.zeros_like(image)
    for c in circles[0]:
        cv2.circle(mask, (c[0], c[1]), c[2], 255, -1, 8)
    masked_image = np.ma.masked_array(image, mask)
    return masked_image.var()
```

Answer (score 2):

You could draw all your circles onto a binary mask, then use this mask to index your image and compute the variance only on this sliced portion on your input image.

For example:

```py
from collections import namedtuple

import cv2
import numpy as np

Circle = namedtuple('Circle', ['cx', 'cy', 'radius'])

image = cv2.imread('lena.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
print(f'Variance (whole): {np.var(image)}')

circles = [
    Circle(cx=45, cy=23, radius=31),
    Circle(cx=321, cy=111, radius=89),
    Circle(cx=465, cy=511, radius=67)
]

circles_mask = np.full(shape=(image.shape[0], image.shape[1]), fill_value=255, dtype=np.uint8)
for circle in circles:
    cv2.circle(circles_mask, (circle.cx, circle.cy), radius=circle.radius,
               color=(0, 0, 0), thickness=cv2.FILLED)

image_masked = image[np.where(circles_mask)]
print(f'Variance (masked): {np.var(image_masked)}')

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('circles_mask', circles_mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**Image used for testing:**

[image: sample image]

**Circles mask:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm always very happy when I find a use case for namedtuple :D